# NSAttributedString in CATextLayer causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS (ios 5.0)

Tags: ios, ios5, core-text, nsattributedstring, quartz-core

I'm having hard time working with CoreText.
Don't know, if I'm doing something wrong or if it's iOS' own bug, but here's what I have:
in iOS 5.0 this code makes app crash while displaying view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

    NSDictionary * attrs = @{(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName:font};

    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test" attributes:attrs];

    CATextLayer * textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];

    textLayer.frame = self.view.frame;

    textLayer.string = attrStr;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
}
```

It makes EXC_BAD_ACCESS and opens `CoreText TAttributes::TAttributes(__CFDictionary const*):` showing line of assembler where exception occurred.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm struggling with it for almost 8 hours and still no clue what is going on.

**UPDATE**

It seems like the problem is somehow based on this line

```
    NSDictionary * attrs = @{(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName:font};
```

because when I remove Font attribute and add ForegroundColor attribute it suddenly starts to work. I will try to dig deeply, but still would like some help.

Comment: @iPatel, what do you mean?

Comment: i mean NSDictionary * attrs is displayed properly or not ??

Comment: @iPatel, it depends on what you mean by "displayed". If you're talking about @{} syntax then yes, it's correct. Otherwise I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Okay..u have good title of you Question..only search on google with your title , there are many resource you found..i tried it :)

Comment: @iPatel, thanks, but I found nothing that could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Core Text directly you must use CTFont, not UIFont. They are *not* mutually compatible (i.e. there is no toll-free bridge between them).

I spent an entire day discovering this. My problems were just like what you're experiencing now!

The wonderful NSAttributedString stuff is, unfortunately, iOS 6 only. So if you want to make a  multistyled string and display it in iOS 5, what you are doing is right. But you must use only iOS 5-compatible calls.

Here's some typical code for making an NSAttributedString that works with CoreText and can be displayed by a CATextLayer on iOS 5:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS5bookExamples/ch23p689styledText1/p579p593styleText1/RootViewController.m

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using CTFontCreateWithName instead of UIFont did the trick.

Comment: I spent so long wrestling with this. Even worse is that using the wrong kind of font sometimes kind of does work, so it took twice as long to figure out. I'm glad my experience was useful to someone else! Wow, that was such a bad day. I still remember it. And why isn't CTFontRef bridged to UIFont???????? Don't get me started.

Comment: NOTE: in iOS 7 they are bridged (at last!)

Answer (score 0):

The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception is a memory issue, which is often an object (early) release issue, i.e. access to an already freed object.

If you don't have NSZombies turned on, do that and try again.  There are certainly many posts pertaining to them here.

Comment: I'm aware of the trivial situations when EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs, but this is definitely not that case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I suspected. You didn't mention them, so I thought I would. Good luck. The Font avenue that @matt mentioned looks possible.