# How do I draw NSAttributedString in iOS5?

Tags: ios5, crash, nsattributedstring

When I try to draw an NSAttributedString and run it in iOS5 simulator I get a crash. In iOS6 it runs fine. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, because from what I read my code should also work on iOS5. My setup:

- xCode 4.6.2
- iOS 6.1 SDK
- iOS 5.1 deployment target

I run the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    NSDictionary *txtAttr = @{
       (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]
    };


    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"foobar" attributes:txtAttr];


    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // flip context
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
// I get a crash on the line below
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
        (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)string
    );
    CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, 0, 4);
    CTLineDraw(line, ctx);
    CFRelease(line);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

This crashes on `CTLineCreateWithAttributedString` with the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00140c68 in TAttributes::TAttributes(__CFDictionary const*) ()
#1  0x0011c499 in TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*) ()
#2  0x0011c313 in TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) ()
#3  0x0010db14 in CTLineCreateWithAttributedString ()
#4  0x00065e5f in -[AttributedLabel drawRect:] at AttributedLabel.m:77
#5  0x003c8bd3 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
#6  0x002a7963 in -[CALayer drawInContext:] ()
#7  0x002b9f80 in backing_callback(CGContext*, void*) ()
#8  0x001d83fd in CABackingStoreUpdate_ ()
#9  0x002b9e2e in CA::Layer::display_() ()
#10 0x002a7a3d in -[CALayer _display] ()
#11 0x002adfd5 in CA::Layer::display() ()
#12 0x002a7a63 in -[CALayer display] ()
#13 0x002b19ae in CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#14 0x00236509 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#15 0x002383f6 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#16 0x00237ad0 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#17 0x0140c99e in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#18 0x013a3640 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#19 0x0136f4c6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#20 0x0136ed84 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#21 0x0136ec9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#22 0x018157d8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#23 0x0181588a in GSEventRun ()
#24 0x0038a626 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

The place where the crash happens is shown below:

```
0x140c5a:  calll  0x11c812                  ; TCFRetained<__CFDictionary const*>::Retain(__CFDictionary const*)
0x140c5f:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x140c62:  movl   4(%eax), %eax
0x140c65:  movl   20(%eax), %eax
0x140c68:  movl   8(%eax), %eax  ;I get a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x08) here
0x140c6b:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x140c6d:  je     0x140d0c                  ; TAttributes::TAttributes(__CFDictionary const*) + 482
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is to use `UIFont`. iOS5 expects a `CTFont`, which is a Core Foundation type. Below is the code I used to get it working:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"HelveticaNeue-Bold", 16, NULL);
NSDictionary *txtAttr = @{
   (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName : (id)CFBridgingRelease(font)
};
```

Use your font book app to locate the font and use the PostScript name. I would not have figured out this if I had not read: [NSAttributedString in CATextLayer causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS (ios 5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814622/nsattributedstring-in-catextlayer-causes-exc-bad-access-ios-5-0?rq=1)

Comment: I am still not certain if this will cause memory to be handled correctly. I can't find any documentation on how CF types which are not toll-free bridges are handled.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want to draw text line by line but here is my code that I used to draw NSAttributedString on a custom UIView:
I changed the code according to your attributed string:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"yourString"];
   UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
   CTFontRef fontR = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL);
   [attrString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName
                               value:(id)fontR 
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourText length])];
   CFRelease(fontR);
   CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
   CTFramesetterRef framesetter =  CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrString);
        // added 3 pixels at the top of the frame so that the text is not cuted
  CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 3, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
  CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, newRect);
  CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
  CFRelease(framesetter);
  CGPathRelease(path);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
  CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
  CTFrameDraw(frameRef, context);
  CFRelease(frameRef);
  [super drawRect:newRect];
```

}

I hope I didn't forgot anything, because I also perform some calculations on the attributed text and I removed them for a better example.

Hope this helps ;)